# Turbo table in PrimeNG with styling

Tags: css, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am using turbo table for displaying data. But I am not getting borders for table. I installed PrimeNG from CLI and imported themes in styles section in *angular-cli.json*.

Comment: Can you provide more information or code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure the following is present :

In your index.html file the following link references:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/redmond/theme.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

Then make sure the styles.css has the right theme import e.g:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Also make sure in your package.json the dependencies is there:

```
"primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
"primeng": "^6.0.0-beta.1"
```